# combox select item display in a list box

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

In WPF and xaml i want to have a combo box with items like list0 - list5

Now, when i select that item or index i want it to display in a list box.

I want it to populate the list box with those words below and the correct index like if i select the first one "List0" it displays in the list box:

```
foo0
bar0
baz0
toto0
tintin0
```

So, when i select "list3" in the combobox

It will display those words with the right index thats selected... can this be done with xaml?

If this cant be done in xaml can i do this in C# with xaml project?

here is a pic of what i want to accomplish!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working XAML-Only example:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="cb" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="List0"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="List1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="List2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="List3"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="List4"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="List5"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <sys:String>foo</sys:String>
                <sys:String>bar</sys:String>
                <sys:String>baz</sys:String>
                <sys:String>toto</sys:String>
                <sys:String>tintin</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
                            <Binding Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding Path="SelectedIndex" ElementName="cb"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```